# how to remove L.tileLayer.wms from a map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geoserver

I create WMS a request to my geoserver, and get my layer

```
var tif1 = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms', {
              layers: 'cite:tiff',
              format: 'image/png',
              transparent: true
        });
```

Next, I create a group using the leaflet library

```
var groupedOverlays = {
        "Растр": tif1
    };
```

And I get L.control.layers , in which the map and my tif are stored

```
 temp=L.control.layers(baseMaps,groupedOverlays).addTo(map);
```

Then, when I call a certain the function, I delete L.control

```
if (temp != undefined) {
    map.removeControl(temp);}
```

Control is deleted and the TIFF itself remains in place, and I can not remove it

I have tried it seems all methods

```
 map.removeLayer(tif1);
 map.removeLayer(temp);
 temp.removeFrom(map)
```

When I call one function, I need all the tif to be removed from the map forever, and I will dynamically add new ones.
How can I remove a tiff from a map that is created through a WMS request?

Comment: What's the value of `tif1` when you run `map.removeLayer(tif1)` ??

Comment: I'm trying to remove the tiff from the image